# Is there any method getContentView like setContentview?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionlistener

I need to get layout name or layout id in the onKeyDown method.
Is there any method to find the current layout name.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) { 

 return true;
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Comment: You can store id as global int variable in your class which extends activity during setContentView and then access it in onKeyDown method.

Comment: How to access in my onKeyDown method.

Comment: post your code of activity i  will show you how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following code.

```
class myactivity extends Activity{
int layoutid;

@Override
public onCreate(Bundle b){
     setContentView(R.id.mainlayout);
     layoutid = R.id.mainlayout;
}

@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) { 
     // here you can access the layoutid variable 
     // implement your logic here
 return true;
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

}

enjoy...